# What's causing this MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException? C#

Tags: c#, database, exception, mysql

I've been looking through my code for a while now and I can not see anything that would cause the following error at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery():

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dllAdditional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

This is my code:

```
public void InsertReservation(Reservation reservation)
{ //To counter the unavailable Auto Increment in the database
    int ReservationID = 0;
    string query = "SELECT max(ReservationID) FROM Reservation";

    if (this.OpenConnection())
    {
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    ReservationID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    CloseConnection();
    }

    ReservationID++;
    string query2 = "INSERT INTO `Reservation`(`ReservationID`, `CarID`, `CustomerID`, `Startdate`, `Enddate`, `Confirmed`, `Kilometres`, `Pickupcity`, `Pickupstreetname`, `Pickupstreetnumber`, `Pickupstreetnumbersuffix`, `Paid`, `Comment`) VALUES(@reservationid,@carid,@customerid,@startdate,@enddate,@confirmed,@Kilometres,@pickupcity,@pickupstreetname,@pickupnumber,@pickupnumbersuffix,@paid,@comment";
    if (this.OpenConnection())
    {
        int convertCofnfirmedToInt;
        int convertPaidtoInt;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query2, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reservationid", ReservationID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carid", reservation.carID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerid", reservation.customerID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", reservation.startdate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", reservation.enddate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@confirmed", reservation.);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kilometres", reservation.kilometres);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pickupcity", reservation.pickupcity);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pickupstreetname", reservation.pickupstreetname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pickupnumber", reservation.pickupstreetnumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pickupnumbersuffix", reservation.pickupstreetnumbersuffix);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paid", paidbool);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", reservation.comment);


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        this.CloseConnection();
    }

}
```

If someone could help me out, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add closing round parenthesis `)` at the end of your sql `INSERT`:

```
string query2 = "INSERT INTO `Reservation`(`ReservationID`, `CarID`, `CustomerID`, `Startdate`, `Enddate`, `Confirmed`, `Kilometres`, `Pickupcity`, `Pickupstreetname`, `Pickupstreetnumber`, `Pickupstreetnumbersuffix`, `Paid`, `Comment`) VALUES(@reservationid,@carid,@customerid,@startdate,@enddate,@confirmed,@Kilometres,@pickupcity,@pickupstreetname,@pickupnumber,@pickupnumbersuffix,@paid,@comment)";
```